# How do I output a numpy array as an image through webpy?

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy

I am trying to follow the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html#scipy.misc.imsave), but when I did the following:

```
web.header('Content-type', 'image/png')
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
scipy.misc.imsave(buf, my_numpy_data, format='png')
return buf.getvalue()
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: imsave() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'
```

**What are valid values for the format parameter?** I tried 'png', 'PNG', 'image/png'. Is there another easy way to do this same thing from a numpy array?

Comment: What is the version of SciPy you are using? And what does `help(scipy.misc.imsave)` tell you?

Comment: I have same error when try to define format. Is it a bug? Any standart solution to define format and save image with custom filename?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by using the Image object from PIL. I used a small function to convert:

```
def array2PIL(data):
  mode = 'RGB'
  size = data.shape[1],data.shape[0]
  return Image.frombuffer(mode, size, data.tostring(), 'raw', mode, 0, 1)
```

and then used it like this:

```
web.header('Content-type', 'image/png')
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
img = array2PIL(my_numpy_data)
img.save(buf,format='PNG')
return buf.getvalue()
```